# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Configuration error when trying to execute test using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, log4j

I am using JUnit to execute an integration test on a Spring Data repository. Here is my setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = User.class)
public class TestUserRepository {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository repo;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // test code here
  }

}
```

I am using Spring Boot **only** for testing. I included the following dependencies in my Gradle build file:

```
testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.11.1'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
```

Before the test even executes, I get the following error. Do I need to configure log4j before I execute the test? How can I solve this error?

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:490)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:460)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:256)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:578)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:145)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:182)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Can you post the `UserRepository` code structure too?

Comment: I would suspect dependencies issue. Please check if you have more than 1 version of the log4j jar by means of transitive dependency.